# dropdown box empty in django when trying to populate values from database

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am new to Django and I was unable to find a fix for this. I am trying to populate a dropdown box with the database values.

Here are my files

models.py file

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Page(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    permalink = models.CharField(max_length=12, unique=True)
    update_date = models.DateTimeField('Last Updated')
    bodytext = models.TextField('Page Content', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Item(models.Model):
    itemId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    itemName = models.CharField(max_length = 100, unique=True)
    itemPrice = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.itemName
```

forms.py file

```
from django import forms
from .models import Item

class OrderListForm(forms.Form):
    itemNames = forms.queryset = Item.objects.all().order_by('itemName')
```

urls.py file

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns =[
    path('',views.OrderListView.as_view(),name ='hello'),

]
```

views.py file

```
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from .forms import OrderListForm

# Create your views here.

class OrderListView(FormView):
    template_name = "myapp/orderlist.html"
    form_class = OrderListForm
    context_object_name = 'itemNames'
```

orderlist.html file

```
<form action="" method = "post">
{% csrf_token %}

<label for="Items">Choose an Item:</label>
<select id = items >
{% for item in itemNames %}
<option value = "">{{item.itemName}}</option>
{% endfor %}
</form>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Changed the view to listview. I am not sure why I used Formview

Here's the code

views.py

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import Item

class OrderListView(ListView):
    template_name = "myapp/orderlist.html"
    context_object_name = 'itemNames'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Item.objects.all()
```

The other answer is to change the html file to

```
<form action="" method = "post">
{% csrf_token %}
<label for="Items">Choose an Item:</label>
{{form.as_p}}
</form>
```